# Laravel 6 No such file or directory driver PDOConnection

Tags: laravel, laravel-6.2

I have next error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
include(/home/xxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/composer/../doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

I tried to change .env and database.php host to localhost or 127.0.0.1  or change port to 33060, composer update / install / dump-autoload , etc (All solution i found on website)

```
  'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'xxxxx'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xxxx'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

Laravel Framework 6.18.6

Comment: you tried put the config content to .env file?

Comment: yes but nothing

Comment: you can not do it like that, so it's not working. they are two different content.

Comment: with or without .env file is the same result.

Comment: This is a weird message. Have you installed using `composer install` ? Maybe clear out the vendor folder, and do `composer clear-cache` then `composer install`. `clear-cache` dumps all your cached packages, and then you reinstall. I opt this because the msg: `No such file or directory (SQL: select * from users)`  is not a normal db-issue.

Comment: yes i used all commands from composer about install , update , cache dump-autoload

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` the migrate again.

Comment: Are you using Docker? If so, you need to specify the host name of the container.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much stronger way of cleaning a confused install...

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Works nearly every time for me, including in cases where this particular error was encountered.